# Can't receive incoming sms body individual words using twilio

Tags: codeigniter, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm using the Twilio PHP API on my site for sending and receive sms.i successfully send sms but i can't receive individual words from incoming sms.suppose a customer sent a sms in my twilio number like="i am going home" now i want to take two words from that line like i,home. can i use this code

```
<?php
    $msg1 = $_REQUEST['Body[0]'];
    $msg2 = $_REQUEST['Body[2]'];
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
?>
```

am i right? or what is the thinks i should change

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The issue here is that you have the square brackets inside the string. Try this instead:

```
<?php
    $body = $_REQUEST['Body'];
    $msg1 = $body[0];
    $msg2 = $body[2];
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
?>
```

Comment: but when reply in number it wasnot take as a one word.suppose a client sent a sms with this format 456 y g and i want to take 456 to in a one string but it was save in three string. How to solve it

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Using square brackets like that will pick individual letters, not words. Check Hasta Dhana's answer, that should be correct.

Comment: how can i get message date from twilio incoming sms?

Comment: You can see all the parameters you receive for an incoming message here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml#request-parameters. The date isn’t sent as part of the webhook. You can fetch it by retrieving the message from the REST API, see the docs for that here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#fetch-a-message-resource

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the first and the last word from the received sms, since the body is just a string you could split the sms body into array, then get the first array and last array :

```
<?php
$array = explode(" ",$_POST['Body']);
$first_word = $array[0];
$last_word  = $array[count($array)-1];

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
?>
```